# I cannot install aptitude tool on ubuntu 16.4

Tags: 16.04

I cannot install aptitude tool on ubuntu 16.4. Whenever I try installing it, an error comes up as follows:

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

What does this mean and how do I solve this??

Answer (score 0):

You need to write `sudo` before your installation. And then enter you password to install aptitude tool.